# Can several different maps share the same keyset?

Tags: java, dictionary

I am working with Java, in particular, but even if this isn't possible in Java, I am interested to know if it's possible in any language at all.

I have a set of Exam objects in a Student class representing the exams the student has taken, and for each Exam in the set, I want to keep track of both the student's responses to the exam questions and I want to keep track of the student's grade on each exam.

The most straightforward way of achieving this is to simply have two maps for each relation. However, I want to be able to guarantee that any key that exists in a map exists for all the maps, and removing a key from any of the maps should remove it from all of the maps. It also seems like it would be more efficient to have a single common keyset when each map's keys are really all representing the same thing: the set of exams the student has taken.

So is it possible to make several different maps depend on the same keyset? And regardless of whether or not it's possible, is there any reason it would just be a bad idea?

Thanks! I appreciate any advice :)

Edit: For the record, I have though about just instantiating a new map, and then iterating through the keyset of the original map adding each key to the new map, but I don't think this will do what I want. I'd be creating a new keyset that just happens to contain all the references of the original keyset. My two maps would not actually be depending on the same keyset so changing one would not affect the other as it should.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. No, it's not a good idea. Coordinating between the maps will be a nightmare, especially when you try to add more maps later on if your needs for the program change. Can you show us the relevant code so we can help you come up with another way of doing things? Show us the `Student` class and the `Exam` class.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a project for school so posting my code here could get me in a lot of trouble :(. I'll take your word for it, and try and find a different approach. Just out of curiosity, how would you do it if it's not too complicated? Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 1):

Well in Java (and most languages) the key set is tightly coupled internally within the `Map` implementation, because it affects how the keys are looked up to find their values. One `Map` could be using a `HashSet` implementation associating the value objects to the keys, and handling hash collisions, while another `Map` could be using a `TreeSet`. You could create your own `Map` implementation but I suspect its just the wrong model.

Why don't you change approach a bit. 
You say that you essentially have one set of keys, the `Student`s, and multiple values, the set of `Exam`s the student took, and the set of `Grade`s for each `Exam`.

So what if you created a new class called `StudentExams` in which you have a `Map<Exam, Grade>`.

```
public class StudentExams {
  private Map<Exam, Grade> examGrades = ... //choose whatever you want

  //... constructor and setter methods here if you need them

  public Set<Exam> getExams() {
     return examGrades.keySet();
  }

  /**
    * Returns the Grade for the exam the student took, 
    * or Optional.empty() if the student did not take that exam.
    */ 
  public Optional<Grade> getGrade(Exam exam) {
     return Optional.ofNullable(examGrades.get(exam));
  }
}
```

Then in your main `Map` you have a `Map<Student, StudentExams>`.

This way for each student you can get his `StudentExams` and extract the set of `Exam` objects together with their `Grade` objects.

Answer (score 0):

> So is it possible to make several different maps depend on the same keyset?

The simplest approach is to have one Map where the value holds all the values of the other maps would have.

This way

- there is only one key set.
- adding a key adds all values.
- removing a key removes all values.

Instead of say

```
Map<String, String> nameMap
Map<String, Long> counterMap
Map<String, Double> scoreMap
```

you instead value

```
class Values {
    String name;
    long counter;
    double score;
}

Map<String, Values> valuesMap;
```

It is possible to create views of this Map so they appear as the original multiple Maps but it is unlikely to be worth the effort.